# Vnc connection through nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, vnc

novnc connection through nginx reverse proxy is not working propraly
i m using nginx version 1.14.1

```
    events {}
http 
{
    server {
       listen 80;
location / {
               proxy_set_header Host $host;
               proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
               proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
               proxy_pass http://192.168.8.1:6080/;
               proxy_http_version 1.1;
               proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
   }
```

when i m using this nginx configuration and access the vnc via http://127.0.0.1:80/ it work fine, but when i change the location from / to /console/ and trying to access via http://127.0.0.1:80/console , it not work !!!

Comment: you don't need to set port 80 in case of using the default port, more over why you want to use localhost to access a different host in your lan, it doesn't make sense except that there is no business case, in that case superuser.com is the right one